# How to add Css and Js files in Django python

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am facing to load static only css and Javascript in my django project. 
By this code image files are loading but only js and css files are not loading

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Home</title>
 <link href="{% static "pro.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="sd">
 <h1>Hi my first django application</h1>
 <img src="{% static "images/img08.jpg" %}"/>
 <div id="demo"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and my page source in browser

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Home</title>
<link href="/static/pro.css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sd">
<h1></h1> 
<img src="/static/images/img08.jpg"/>
<div id="demo"></div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

my setting files code`

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=     (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'questions','static','css'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'questions','static','js'),)
```

I got this error message when i checked in my Javascript console -
127.0.0.1/:19 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css:

Comment: use {% load staticfiles %} at the top of your html page

Comment: AjayGupta .I did that . My all Images are loading by same way only css and Js files are not loading. I am using Eclipse IDE for Django.

Comment: where is your STATIC_URL pointing at? and are you running using django server or any other server like apache, nginx?

Comment: I am running my Project at localhost. STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'questions','static','css'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'questions','static','js'),)

Comment: are your files in some css and js directory?

Comment: Even I am giving absolute path of css still not wroking.<link href="C:\Users\sumit\workspace\project\doyouknow\questions\static\css\pro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: have you done `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: @sumitchansouliya: check answer below.

Comment: Check if the answer below solves your issue!

Comment: replace your link line with this line `<link href="{% static "pro.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`. Notice the closing `"`

Comment: @Ymartin I have done . Nothing Happend.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is for project (common) statics:

   ```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   )
   ```
2. And this is for your apps statics:

   ```
   STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   )
   ```

Then in template you can access it using:

```
{% load static %}

{# this is in project static dir == tip №1 == static/... #}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static ' js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



{# suppose your app name is `questions` == tip №2 == questions/static/questions/... #}    

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'questions/js/some.js' %}"></script>
<link href="{% static 'questions/css/pro.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<link href="{% static "css/pro.css" %} rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

same applies for js.

You have given path for images as static `"images/image_name.jpg"` but missing the same for css and js files

Comment: I did not create any extra folder for css and js. they are just in static folder but i created images folder inside static folder so I gave path like this.

Comment: see that's the problem, you static_file seting says its in css and js folder respectively. Either update your setting or add css and js folder in their respective folder

Comment: Ajay I tried that also. Nothing happend. Even when i am giving complete absolute path of my css file still css is not working. <link href="C:\Users\sumit\workspace\project\doyouknow\questions\static\css\pro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: edit your question and add your static file settings

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are missing is collectstatic

run this command

`python manage.py collectstatic`

docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have run this command and my all static files have copied in respective directory. my all image files are loading but only css and js are not loading

Answer (score 0):

It was my problem too!
but i solve it :

1. you should go to your project setting `setting.py`and find  `STATIC_URL`
2. note url which is in `STATIC_URL` then change it to the path of absolute static files
   for example my path is `MySite/MyApp/static/My_App/'static files'`
3. after that copy the path of your `My_app` to the `STATIC_URL` then it should work.

**Note:** you should insert your path in `STATIC_URL` with this format:

```
/file1/ or `/file1/file2/.../`
```

hope useful

Comment: one thing omitted is you should type {% load static %} if you change the filename to 'static'.